# Get name attribute from dropzone using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone with L5.5 and I want to store one image for profile and multiple images for the gallery.
I put the `paramName:` to Dropzone configuration, but I can't upload the two instances of Dropzone, just one.

Gives me an error:  http://127.0.0.1/project/public/dropzone/store 500 (Internal Server Error)

My view:

```php
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>Upload Multiple Images</h1>
    {!! Form::open([ 'route' => [ 'dropzone.store' ], 'files' =>  true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class' => '', 'id' => '' ]) !!}            
        <div class="dropzone" id="image-upload1">
            <h3>Upload Multiple Image By Click On Box</h3>
        </div>

        {!! Form::text('name'); !!}

        <div class="dropzone" id="image-upload">
            <h3>Upload Multiple Image By Click On Box</h3>
        </div>

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit-all">OK</button>

   {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

My Dropzone js:

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

//>>> IMAGE 1
var myDropzone1 = new Dropzone("div#image-upload1", { 
    url: "dropzone/store",
    paramName: "profile",
    autoProcessQueue:false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    maxFilesize:5,
    maxFiles:1,
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    init: function(){
        myDropzone1 = this; // closure
        var btn1 = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
        btn1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            //myDropzone1.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
        });
    }
});
// MULTIPLE THE SAME LIKE ONE

$("#submit-all").click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    myDropzone1.processQueue();
    //myDropzone.processQueue();
    //$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

On my controller:

```php
public function dropzoneStore(Request $request)
{
    $dir = public_path().'/upload/';

    $files1 = $request->file('profile');

    foreach($files1 as $file1){
        $fileName1 = $file1->getClientOriginalName();
        $file1->move($dir, $fileName1);
    }

    // FOR MULTIPLE
    $files = $request->file('images');
    foreach($files as $file){
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($dir, $fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Enable Debugging:
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
and check your log files for any errors

Comment: `500 server error` is just a generic message, the real error, which will tell you exactly what is wrong, will be in your `storage/logs/laravel.log`, and/or your webserver (Apache, nginx) and/or PHP logs.  What is the real error?

Comment: this is the error of laravel: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php  on this line:throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others); ------- and the laravel.log gave me this: C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))

Comment: @Leoh OK, that shows the real problem - I've added an answer, please have a look.

Comment: Im trying right now.. i have this on my network dev tool of chrome.. message: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()", exception: "ErrorException" and the line is: foreach($files1 as $file1){
            $fileName1 = $file1->getClientOriginalName();
            $file1->move($dir, $fileName1);
        }

Comment: OK, this is a new error msg, right? How did you get past `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`? For your current problem, do all your Dropzones have the same `paramName`?

Comment: different paramNames: var myDropzone = new Dropzone(
        '"div#image-upload1"', //id of drop zone element 1
        {
     url: "dropzone/store",
            paramName: "profile",
        }
    );

var myDropzone1 = new Dropzone(
        '"div#image-upload"', //id of drop zone element 2
        {
     url: "dropzone/store",
            paramName: "images",
        }
    );

Comment: OK, so there's your answer! :-) Did my answer to the previous question help?

Comment: but I what two different paramNames, one for one image for profile and other paramName to image gallery, if like i have two normal input file in one form, but with dropzone

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is

- Create 2 different forms if you're doing the upload via Ajax
- Create 2 different inputs if your upload is via POST

I had a similar problem on the past but it was a problem of concern.

Currently you have both Dropzones on the same Form, but Dropzone creates it's own form I think.

Also, check that 500 error better, maybe gives you a clue about what's going on. Look at `storage/logs/laravel.log` and, if there's nothing useful, in logs of your web server.

Comment: i want to save in one form only, all the inputs, if i put this works fine, but when i use two paramName gave me an error. $files = $request->file('file');
        

        foreach($files as $file){
            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($dir, $fileName);
        }

Answer (score 0):

The real error, from your comment, is:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illumin‌​ate\Routing\RouteCol‌​lection.php on this line: throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` means that you don't have a suitable route set up for the request you are making.  Usually this is something like POSTing to a URL where there is only a GET route set up, or `redirect()`ing - which issues a GET - after successful handling of the POST to a URL where there is only a POST route set up.

Another common case is if you have validation in the method which receives the POST.  If that validation fails, [Laravel will `redirect()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) back to the previous page, with a GET request.  You need a GET route set up for that to work.

As you do have a POST route correctly set up (described in your comments), it must be one of the other cases.

Comment: Of course I have a route: Route::post('dropzone/store', ['as'=>'dropzone.store','uses'=>'HomeController@dropzoneStore']); Maybe the problem is use two request->file();

Comment: @Leoh `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` means a request was made to an existing route but with a different method - eg POST request made to a route where there is only GET configured, etc. Have a look in browser devtools network tab - which request is throwing error?

Comment: Or maybe it is the request that happens after your `dropzoneStore` method is complete - eg a `redirect()` to some "success" page, using GET, where that route is not configured? What happens after the `dropzoneStore` method completes, is there a redirect or new request happening somewhere?